# Нестабильная работа отправки сообщений с сайта

Tags: php, wordpress, хостинг

Я в back-end не силен, потому задаю возможно такой банальный вопрос.

У меня есть хостинг и тестовый домен: http://co71038.tmweb.ru

Оставляешь заявку, и почему-то когда в качестве email администратора стоит мой email приходит моментально.

Но на другие email. Приходят с огромной задержкой, а порой я даже сомневаюсь, что приходят (сейчас отправил пару заявок и уже спустя 20 минут ничего не пришло)

Установил плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Никак не повлияло. Кто с таким сталкивался, подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Использую следующий код для отправки сообщений.

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_fs', 'mig_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fs', 'mig_mail');

function mig_mail (){
    $recepient = get_bloginfo('admin_email');

    $siteName = get_bloginfo();

    $data = urldecode($_POST['data']);
    parse_str( $data, $arr );

    $name     = !empty($arr['name'])   ? "Имя: "       . trim($arr['name'])   . "\n" : "";
    $tel      = !empty($arr['phone'])  ? "Телефон: +"  . trim($arr['phone'])  . "\n" : "";
    $email    = !empty($arr['email'])  ? "Email: "     . trim($arr['email'])  . "\n" : "";
    $text     = !empty($arr['review']) ? "Сообщение: " . trim($arr['review']) . "\n" : "";

    if (empty($text)){
        $pageTitle = "Заявка с сайта \"$siteName\"";
    } else {
        $pageTitle = "Отзыв с сайта \"$siteName\"";
    }


    $message = "$name$tel$email$text";

    wp_mail(
        $recepient,
        $pageTitle,
        $message,
        "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient"
    );

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Во `From` должен стоять реальный email адрес соответствующий адресу сервера с которого идет отправка. Если это не так, то вы получаете проблемы.

Comment: Email для ответа на такое письмо нужно прописывать в `Reply-To`.

Comment: И в самом деле, а что у вас From не указано? Последний параметр у wp_mail должен выглядеть примерно так: `'From: ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . " <noreply@co71038.tmweb.ru>\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Кроме того, в dns должны быть созданы записи spf и dkim, чтобы ваша почта не летела в спам.

Comment: E-mail, на который еле письма доходят, случайно не mail.ru?

Comment: По поводу задержки - 99% надо пилить хостера. А такую форму нельзя использовать Как минимум из-за отсутствия FROM, но не только. Используй плагины. Ида. для логгироания почты в ВП тоже есть плагины.